# Polar co-ordinates dr/dtheta

Tags: derivatives, polar-coordinates

How can you visualise what is the curve doing by calculating Dr/dtheta in polar co-ordinates form. 
Also, what will it mean for Dr/dtheta to be zero?
Thank you.

Comment: $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$ is a measure of how much the distance from the origin is changing at a point given a little change in angle.  If this is zero then the curve at that point looks very similar to a circle (only locally).

Comment: Will a negative value imply that it's coming towards the centre ? If I am right

Comment: It means that if you move along the curve *in the counterclockwise direction* (the positive direction of $\theta$) the curve is coming towards the centre, yes.

Comment: Will it mean anything if we write in parametric form and find out dr/dt =0 ?

Comment: That would mean that locally the distance doesn't change with a little change in $t$.  What the curve actually looks like would depend on the $t$-dependence of $\theta$.

Comment: Ok. I think my question is answered. Thanks for the help.